# Count number of rows within each month of a datetime, group by year month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, group-by

I'm having trouble getting a sproc to give me this type of output:

```
+-----------+------------------+
|   Month   | NoOfModifcations |
+-----------+------------------+
| Jan  2008 |                5 |
| Nov  2008 |                6 |
| Feb  2010 |               20 |
| Jul  2013 |                7 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

So far i managed to get the output to look like this, but i haven't yet managed to get the output to be sorted by year, then month - it's going alphabetically. Here's what i have so far:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(4), YEAR(LastModifedDate)) + ' ' + convert(varchar(3),datename(month, LastModifedDate)) as Dates,
    count(*) as Number

FROM aims.Modification

WHERE CompanyID = @companyID 
    AND LastModifedDate >= DATEADD(month, @numberOfMonths * -1, GETDATE())

GROUP BY convert(varchar(4), YEAR(LastModifedDate)) + ' ' + convert(varchar(3),datename(month, LastModifedDate))
```

I did try an ORDER BY on the datetime field but got:

```
Column "aims.Modification.LastModifedDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

It's also very messy on converting/selecting/group by on the datetime to string. Any advice there would also be very helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the results are being outputted to a web page or something like that, add another string to your query that represents the date in yyyymm format.  Order by that field and don't display it in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(LastModifedDate)) + ' ' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATENAME(MONTH,LastModifedDate)) AS Dates,
        COUNT(*) as Number
FROM aims.Modification
WHERE CompanyID = @companyID 
    AND LastModifedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,@numberOfMonths * -1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(LastModifedDate)) + ' ' + 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATENAME(MONTH,LastModifedDate)),
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),LastModifedDate,112)
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),LastModifedDate,112)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT YEAR(LastModifedDate), MONTH(month) as Dates, count(*) as Number
FROM aims.Modification
WHERE CompanyID = @companyID 
    AND LastModifedDate >= DATEADD(month, @numberOfMonths * -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(LastModifedDate), MONTH(LastModifiedDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(LastModifedDate), MONTH(LastModifiedDate)
```

Keep it simple and make the concatenation in your C# code or report...

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert your varchar to datetime

```
 SELECT CONVERT(Datetime,'Jan  2008 ')
```

Then sort your column based upon datetime desc. 
Sorry for short and unfinished answer, Hope it helps.